# Dealing with multiple input fields and OK buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got multiple sets of input fields and a button for each set.

The user has to fill the input fields of each set and click the relevant OK button. Now instead of having to the click the OK button, how can I enable the enter key to trigger the RELEVANT the OK button (depending on which set of input fields the user filled)? Usually I do this as below but how do I do it with multiple input fields and buttons?

```
    $('#open').keypress(function(e){
      if(e.keyCode==13){
        $('#search').trigger('click');
      }
    });
```

Below is an example of the input fields and OK buttons

```
Apples: <input type="text" name="apple"><br>
Mangos: <input type="text" name="mango"><br>
<button id="part1">OK</button>

Carrots: <input type="text" name="carrot"><br>
Beans: <input type="text" name="beans"><br>
<button id="part3">OK</button>

Tom Hanks: <input type="text" name="hanks"><br>
Heidi Klum: <input type="text" name="klum"><br>
<button id="part2">OK</button>
```

When the user fills `Tom Hanks` and `Heidi Klum` input fields, the enter key should click `#part2` button.
When the user fills `Apples` and `Mangos` input fields, the enter key should click `#part1` button.

Comment: just give those inputs `ids` too and handle those? or pack each of those fieldsets in an actual `fieldset` tag and use a sibling selector?

Comment: @nonchip Thank you. Assuming each input field has IDs, but I do not know how to handle triggering the relevant OK button depending on the completed input fields.

Comment: you can wrap each block into `<form>...</form>` and no need handle keypress

Comment: @GeneR Thank you. I'm looking for a way to do this without using form tags.

Comment: I think you need to bind them. Something either using the `this` keyword or `.bind` Try `$('#open').keypress(function(e){
      if(e.keyCode==13){
        $('#search').trigger('click');
      }
    }).bind(this)`

Comment: well, e.g. if you have inputs with IDs like `group1_input1`,`group1_input2` and their buttons have id's like `group1_ok`, you just check `e.target.id`, split it at `_` and append `_ok`, and you know the id of the button. but i'd strongly suggest to go with `form`s and `fieldset`s instead, cause that's simply how it's done.

Comment: @Becky: why don't you want to use `form`s?

Comment: @nonchip Thank you. Because I was thinking if could use a class for each set and do the triggering. Was expecting to know the best way to do this rather than the adding from tags. Is adding a class a good way?

Comment: no, adding a `form` or `fieldset` is. DOM and HTML/XML/SGML are hierarchic trees for a reason. so maybe you wanna answer the question above: why don't you want to add a parent element around these groups?

Comment: nothing will be submitted or similar. So I tried to avoid forms.

Comment: i'm pretty sure something will be submitted, just not to a GET/POST url. so just omit the `form`'s `target` attribute and use it for what it says in the name: a form. if `form` would imply submitting something to somewhere, it would be called `submitter`, not `form`. it's a form and if you don't want the plain "submit it to an url" logic, omit the `target` and do the logic yourself (which is what you're doing anyway i suspect, cause you wouldn't need input if you didn't have some logic to handle it)

Comment: @nonchip Thanks for that. Any thoughts on the data attributes as `Gene R`'s answer?

Comment: look like that's gonna work, but it's still not the best style, cause you're still bound to hardcoding different IDs for it to work. if you'd just depend on siblings, it would just work wherever you have such a fieldset, without requiring you to keep track of their IDs (which will become tricky if you start generating those elements by JS or copy'n'paste them around).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

html:

```
<div id="open">
Apples: <input type="text" name="apple" data-button-id="part1"><br>
Mangos: <input type="text" name="mango" data-button-id="part1"><br>
<button id="part1">OK</button>

Carrots: <input type="text" name="carrot" data-button-id="part3"><br>
Beans: <input type="text" name="beans" data-button-id="part3"><br>
<button id="part3">OK</button>

Tom Hanks: <input type="text" name="hanks" data-button-id="part2"><br>
Heidi Klum: <input type="text" name="klum" data-button-id="part2"><br>
<button id="part2">OK</button>
</div>
```

js:

```
$(function(){
  $('#open').on('keypress', 'input', function(e){
    if(e.keyCode==13){
       $('#'+$(e.target).data('buttonId')).trigger('click');
    }
  });
});
```

**Update (alternative):**

```
<div id="open">
<div class="block">
  Apples: <input type="text" name="apple"><br>
  Mangos: <input type="text" name="mango"><br>
  <button class="submit">OK</button>
</div>
<div class="block">
  Carrots: <input type="text" name="carrot"><br>
  Beans: <input type="text" name="beans"><br>
  <button class="submit">OK</button>
</div>
<div class="block">
  Tom Hanks: <input type="text" name="hanks"><br>
  Heidi Klum: <input type="text" name="klum"><br>
  <button class="submit">OK</button>
</div>
</div>
```

js:

```
$(function(){
  $('#open').on('keypress', 'input', function(e){
    if(e.keyCode==13){
      $(e.target).closest('.block').find('.submit').trigger('click'); 
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way that doesn't require you to add an extra attribute to your elements. It works by letting jQuery find the next available submission button, using `nextAll()`:

HTML:

```
<div>
    Apples: <input type="text" name="apple"><br>
    Mangos: <input type="text" name="mango"><br>
    <button id="part1" class="submit">OK</button>
</div>

<div>
    Carrots: <input type="text" name="carrot"><br>
    Beans: <input type="text" name="beans"><br>
    <button id="part3"  class="submit">OK</button>
</div>
<div>
    Tom Hanks: <input type="text" name="hanks"><br>
    Heidi Klum: <input type="text" name="klum"><br>
    <button id="part2" class="submit">OK</button>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var buttonEl;

    $('input').on('focus', function() {
        buttonEl = $(this).nextAll('button.submit').eq(0);        
    });

    $(document).keypress(function(e){        
      if(e.keyCode==13){
        buttonEl.trigger('click');
      }
    });    

    $('button').on('click', function() {
        alert($(this).attr('id'));
    });
});
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sysnull/4m38y5pe/